# Play a short audio while recording?

Tags: objective-c

I need play a short audio while recording. Run on Simualtor is very well but can't play audio when on device while recording . I see SpeakHere example and change "kAudioSessionCategory_RecordAudio" to "kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord".

Anybody help me ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the solution .. Try this:

```
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord; 
status |= AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category);
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
status |= AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                            kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers,  // 1
                                            sizeof (allowMixing),                                 // 2
                                            &allowMixing                                          // 3
                                            );
status |= AudioSessionSetProperty (
                                   kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck,  // 1
                                   sizeof (allowMixing),                                 // 2
                                   &allowMixing                                          // 3
                                   );
```

The final two `AudioSessionSetProperty` calls are new in the 3.0 OS.